# Connection string from Visual WebDeveloper to SQL Server Express database for login screen

Tags: html, asp.net, sql, sql-server-express

I'm trying to create a simple login screen using Visual WebDeveloper aspx page and SQL Server Express.

My SQL Server name is `SPAZZ\SQLEXPRESS`.

I have a database called `H2H` and a table inside the database called `tblUserUser`. Inside the `tblUserUser` table I have 2 columns `sUserName` and `sPassword`.

On the front .aspx page I have 2 textboxes and a button here's the code

```
 <tr>
 <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
 <td colspan="2">User name:</td>
 <td colspan="2"><asp:TextBox name="txtUserName" tabIndex="1" ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
 <td colspan="2"></td>
 </tr>     

 <tr>
 <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
 <td colspan="2"><label>Password :</label></td>
 <td colspan="2"><asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode=Password></asp:TextBox></td>
 <td colspan="2"></td>     
 </tr>     

 <tr>
 <td colspan="2"></td>
 <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
 <td colspan="2"><asp:Button class="button" ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Log In"/></td>
 <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
```

Here's my code on the .aspx.vb page

'This is where I think the problem lies with the imports

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer
Imports H2H.Database.Connection.DataConnector

'and this is the rest of the code 
Partial Class Login1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim oDB As New H2H.Database.Connection.DataConnector

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim oReader As SqlDataReader
        Dim sSQL As String

        sSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblUserUser where sUserName = '" & txtUserName.Text & "' and sPassword = '" & txtPassword.Text & "'"
        oReader = oDB.getData(sSQL)
        If oReader Is Nothing Then

        Else
            If oReader.Read Then
                Response.Write("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>")
                Response.Write("alert('it workd now youl go to next page!');")
                Response.Write("</script>")
                Response.Write("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>")
                'this is the next page
                'Response.Write("document.location='HomePage.aspx?sUser=" & oReader.Item("UserFullName").ToString & " " & oReader.Item("sSurname").ToString & "&sUserID=" & oReader.Item("PkiRekorkId").ToString & "'")
                Response.Write("</script>")

            End If
        End If

        oReader.Close()
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I've been googling for days and cant find an answer please help

Comment: And what is your error?

Comment: the problem must lie with the imports part i cant give you a error

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection. Also: I **sincerely hope** that you're **NOT** actually storing your passwords in **clear text** in the database table!!

Comment: `Imports H2H.Database.Connection.DataConnector` without the asterisk

Comment: i put the astrix to ephasise where the problem lies

Comment: Not sure because i can't see the hierarchy of your classes but it seems that you need to: `Imports H2H.Database.Connection` and then declare `Dim oDB As New DataConnector`

Comment: the thing is it doesnt read anything from my database so theres no connection to the database so even if i put in the wrong password it gives the same problem

Comment: So the problem lies in the getData() and in the connection string used, but both are not shown here and you say that there is no error message?

Comment: i dnt have to use my method if you can just show me a method on how to do this